# Tooltips disapper

Tags: charts, powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I created a graph with tooltips and the tooltips have another tooltip inside. The problem is when I move a little the mouse to enter in tooltips (graph) it disapper How to I resolve it? I want to stop the graph tooltips and see the inside tooltip

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and it is not possible to have tooltips within tooltips. It is also not a great user experience and you'd be better to rethink the way you want to visualise the data.